# Entity Framework 6 optional one way relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have two tables:

```
Client
------------------------
Id           (string) <-- PrimaryKey
Name         (string)
Number       (int)

Department:*
------------------------
Id           (int) <-- Primary key
Name         (string)
ClientNumber (int?)
Client       (Client, virtual)
.....
```

Now I want to create an optional relationship from Departmant to Client (using ClientNumber). I've created a virtual property in the Department class (Client) and now I need to configure the relation using EntityTypeConfiguration.

There are **no foreign keys** configured in the database and I'm not able to change the database. I can't change the Entity (class) Client either.

So I need to tell EntityFramework that the ClientNumber in the Department class is related (optionally) to the Number property in the Client class.

But I can't figure out how to tell EF that the Department's *ClientNumber* is related to the Client's *Number* property, not the Client's primary key. (without changing the Client entity class)

edit: The *Number* property on Client is unique for each entry.

The relation should result in a sql statement like this:

```
SELECT .....
FROM Department D LEFT OUTER JOIN Client C ON (D.ClientNumber = C.Number)
```

It's easy to do this using joins in Linq, but it would be great to just:

```
dbContext.Departments.Include(d => d.Client)
```

using a virtual property on Department class containing the Client (if any)

Comment: It is also still not possible to create relations in entity framework without using primary key columns. If you want to realize that relationship, you have to include the client Id column as foreign key column. 
If that´s for somehow reason not wanted, you could create a view to model that relationship.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) Mentioned this is not "yet" possible .
Entity Framework 7 will support this Feature.

For those who want to be kept up to date, here is the Feature Discussion / Voting.

[Unique Constraint (i.e. Candidate Key) Support](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is not possible. 
Valide relationship in EF must be also valid in the database, in other words the dependent table must be referring a unique identifier in the principal table. Otherwise the system cannot ensure that there is at most one client per department.

Comment: Not entirely true. The relationship should refer to a property that EF *knows* as primary key. It could be `Client.Number`, but then that property should be defined as primary key in the model. EF 7 will support alternate keys.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, would you be able to add both a ClientId and ClientNumber property? You can than access ClientNumber from the virtual Client property after ensuring that Client is not null:

```
    public class Client
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class Department 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int? ClientNumber {
            get {
                return Client != null ? Client.Number : null;
            }
        }
    }
```